# Some HD videos on low-end laptop stuttering/lagging

Tags: video, vlc, playback, hd-video

I have the latest version of Ubuntu MATE 64-bit on a low-end laptop/notebook (specs at the bottom).

I've been trying to play HD video, and it's been very inconsistent. It will play some videos fine, while other videos will lag/stutter (caused by CPU hitting 100%). The problem is, the videos that play fine are often much much higher quality than the videos it struggles with.

For example:

**Game of Thrones s05e08 - Hardhome** (plays fine)

> Size: 4.96GB
>   Length: 59m59s
>   Format: .mkv
>   *Video:*
>   Resolution: 1920x1078
>   Data rate: 11,467kbps
>   Total bitrate: 11,851kbps
>   *Audio:*
>   Bit rate: 384kbps
>   Channels: 6
>   Audio sample rate: 48kHz

**Mr. Robot s02e09 - eps2.7_init_5.fve**  (stutters/lags)

> Size: 738MB
>   Length: 49m10s
>   Format: .mkv
>   *Video:*
>   Resolution: 1920x1080
>   Data rate: 1,712kbps
>   Total bitrate: 2,096kbps
>   *Audio:*
>   Bit rate: 384kbps
>   Channels: 6
>   Audio sample rate: 48kHz

By all logic, if my laptop can play the episode of Game of Thrones flawlessly, it should be able to play the episode of Mr. Robot without a hitch.

This isn't the case though. Mr. Robot runs very choppy and laggy. I've tried multiple video players (VLC, smplayer, mplayer, mpv media player, Gnomemplayer, kodi), all with the same results.

In Game of Thrones, my CPU sits under 50% usage. In Mr. Robot the CPU usage hits 100% regularly which causes stuttering and lag in the video. I don't have much RAM installed, but even when the CPU is hitting 100% in Mr. Robot the RAM never gets above 50% usage.

**PC Specs:**

> CPU: Intel Celeron N3050 (2M cache, up to 2.16GHz)
>   RAM: 2GB
>   Storage: 32GB SSD
>   OS: Ubuntu MATE 16.04.1 64-bit
>   *Extra info:*
>   Window Manager: Compiz (anything else causes screen-tearing in video playback)

As a control: Both videos have been tested on my high-end gaming PC which runs Windows 10, and they work fine.

Comment: It might help if you specify the graphics card or chipset, and what video encoding is used in the sample videos. E.g. playing h.264 requires more processing power than xvid/divx with certain video cards.

Comment: … and HEVC (H.265) requires more processing power than AVC (H.264). Furthermore, even within the same codec family there are different levels of "complexity" for codec features, so that it may be more computationally expensive to decode a ~2 Mbps stream of high complexity than a ~10 Mbps stream of low complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an issue of different codecs giving you different performance.

*Not an expert on the matter, so take the considerations below with a grain of salt.*

That said, a smaller file or lower bitrate (in theory) does not necessarily have to result in better playback performance, it could even result in worse playback performance.

For example, if we imagine an encoding that saves bandwidth by computing the current frame based on the frame before (e.g. just contains the pixels that actually change), that would be more taxing on the CPU compared to one that simply has the full data for every frame.

An additional catch would be that the player would not be able to simply skip a frame (something the viewer might not even notice) in a situation where we hit a CPU bottleneck, since it needs that frame in order to compute the next frame.